# select elements in a list by the occurrence of zeros in python

Tags: python, list, selection, python-itertools, zero

Given a 2D list:

```
X = [ [a,2], [b,12], [c,6], [d,0], [e,2], [f,0], [g,0], [h,12], [i,18] ]
```

I need to get a 2D list that groups all the sublists, separated by zeros in the `X[1]` column. I mean, I need to select:

```
Y = [ [[a,2],[b,12],[c,6]], [[e,2]], [[h,12],[i,18]] ]
```

ang get a list of the corresponding `X[0]` entries only:

```
Y = [ [a, b, c], [e], [h, i] ]
```

I've already asked a similar question for selecting elements within a list, on the basis of the occurrences of zeros inside it, but it was a 1D list. Using itertools, I tried something like:

```
Z = [list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(X[:,1], lambda x: x == 0) if not k]
```

where I used `X[:,1]` to act on the `X[1]` part of the list, as the selection acts on it. But it obviously gives me the `X[1]` part of the list:

```
Z = [[2, 12, 6], [2], [12, 18]]
```

But I need the `X[0]` column... how can I use itertools on multi-dimensional lists? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is not clear enough. what is your input and what is the expected output? 'seperated by zeros'? i didn't see zeros in your example. tried to understand for two minutes and failed

Comment: The input in `X `and the desired output is `Y` (the second one). And zeros are in the `X[1]` part of the `X` list (`[d,0], [f,0], [g,0]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do the work:

```
[map(lambda a:a[0],list(v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0) if not k]
```

**More explanation:**

you want to groupby X according to the second value of each item in the list so you need to do:
`itertools.groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0)`

`[list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0) if not k]`
will create the 2D list like that:
`[[['a', 2], ['b', 12], ['c', 6]], [['e', 2]], [['h', 12], ['i', 18]]]`
so you need to manipulate each item in the list and take only the second index, this can be done with the `map` function:

```
[map(lambda a:a[0],list(v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0) if not k]
```

Comment: That's a really ugly and opaque mix of itertools, list comprehension, functional idiom builtins, and lambda expressions. I know you're right but I can't in good conscience upvote this code unless you split it onto a few lines and make it readable. Your code shouldn't require so much explanation if you don't try to cram it onto one line. Just use descriptive names.

Comment: I dont think that those is doing what he expect to have, where is this `Y = [ [[a,2],[b,12],[c,6]], [[e,2]], [[h,12],[i,18]] ]`?

Comment: @machineyearning I've tried to find a solution as similar as possible to what he tried to do, maybe  I'll add better solution if I will find one

Comment: @DanielSanchez That `Y` was only a step for the solution, he wrote it to explain what he is looking for.

Comment: Well, thanks for the hint. Basically, what I was mistaking was the `x[1]` condition in `itertools.groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0)`. The `map` thing doesn't work for me, but ok, now I'm getting a 3D list and I can select the entries I need after.

Comment: what error you get from the `map`? why it does not work?

Comment: I fixed it. You wrote `a:a[1]` but what I wanted were the `a[0]` entries. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: oh sry, I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own splitter using an iterator:

```
def splitter(L):
    group = []
    res = []
    for i in iter(L):
        if i[1]:
            group.append(i[0])
        if not i[1] and len(group):
            res.append(group)
            group = []
    if len(group):
        res.append(group)
    return res

#In [62]: splitter(X)
#Out[62]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e'], ['h', 'i']]
```

If you work with characters, here is an approach - despite I prefer the splitter for your particular problem:

```
[list(u) for u in ''.join([i[0] if i[1] else '|' for i in X]).split("|") if u]
#[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e'], ['h', 'i']]
```

I would also improve/shorten @Elisha answer with a small hack:

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(zip(*v)[0]) for k, v in groupby(X, lambda x: x[1] == 0) if not k]
```

Comment: Shortest != best. This one is code that doesn't need comments and is easy to follow. But why  `iter(L)` where plain `L` will do? Personally would prefer `len(group) != 0` in the tests: makes it even easier to read, though functionally identical.

Comment: iter(L) is a reflex since I normally use iterators. I think `len(group)` is more explicit than `if i[1]` :) But yes, you are right, one could explicitely mentionned the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this:

```
X = [ ['a',2], ['b',12], ['c',6], ['d',0], ['e',2], ['f',0], ['g',0], ['h',12], ['i',18] ]
ind = [-1] + [i for i in range(n) if X[i][1]==0] + [len(X)] # found the indices of the "zero" lists
Y = [X[ind[i]+1:ind[i+1]] for i in range(len(ind)-1)] # choose the items between those indices
Y = [[x[0] for x in list] for list in Y] # take only X[0]
Y
#output
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e'], [], ['h', 'i']]
```

It's just found the "zero" indices and then using slices to get the right lists of lists.

Of course you can remove the empty lists at the end.